# How to check if a blob already exists in Azure blob container using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have a Windows PowerShell script that uploads a file to my Azure Blob Storage.
I want the file only to upload if it doesn't already exists in the container.

How do I check if the blob already exists ?

I tired to use [Get-AzureStorageBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806392.aspx) but if the blob doesn't exists, it returns an error. Should I parse the error message to determine that the blob doesn't exists ? This doesn't seem right...

And [Set-AzureStorageBlobContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806379.aspx) is asking for a confirmation when the blob exists. Is there a way to automatically answer "No" ? This cmdlet doesn't have -confirm and -force would overwrite the file (which I don't want).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A solution is to wrap the call to **Get-AzureStorageBlob** in a try/catch and catch ***ResourceNotFoundException*** to determine that the blob doesn't exist.

And don't forget the `-ErrorAction Stop` at the end.

```
try
{   
    $blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $azureBlobName -Container $azureStorageContainer -Context $azureContext -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.ResourceNotFoundException]
{
    # Add logic here to remember that the blob doesn't exist...
    Write-Host "Blob Not Found"
}
catch
{
    # Report any other error
    Write-Error $Error[0].Exception;
}
```

Comment: Does this approach download the blob if it exists? Can we just check some property of the blob to see whether it exists?

Comment: @derek No,this cmd only lists blobs. The cmd that downloads is: `Get-AzureStorageBlobContent`.

Answer (score 18):

This is a variant of @Chris's answer. Chris used Exceptions and Try/Catch. In larger systems try/catch is great. It allows an error deep in the code to throw an exception, and the system will backtrack the call history looking for a matching catch statement. However when all the code is in one function, for simplicity, I prefer checking return values:

```
$blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $azureBlobName -Container $azureStorageContainer -Context $azureContext -ErrorAction Ignore
if (-not $blob)
{
    Write-Host "Blob Not Found"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right, `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` doesn't have neither `-Confirm` flag nor `-WhatIf` flag.

Are you really sure you want to ignore the fact that particular blob contains something and just overwrite it's content silently?

It looks like that the only one possible (and pretty ugly one) solution here will be a `try`/`catch` block with `Get-AzureStorageBlob` inside.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, I've added a more elaborate answer with a code sample based on your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ErrorAction Stop | where-object {$_.StorageAccountName -eq $StorageAccountName}
     If($storageAccount)
     {
        $key = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName -name $storageAccount.StorageAccountName -ErrorAction Stop)[0].value
        $storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount.StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $key -ErrorAction Stop
        $storageContainer = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $storageContext -ErrorAction Stop | where-object {$_.Name -eq $ContainerName}
        If($storageContainer)
        {
            $blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $storageContext -Container $ContainerName -ErrorAction Stop | where-object {$_.Name -eq $BlobName}
            If($blob)
            {
                Write-Host "'$BlobName' blob found."
            }
            Else 
            {
                Write-Warning "'$BlobName' blob not found."
            }
        }
        Else 
        {
            Write-Warning "'$ContainerName' storage container not found."
        }
     }
     Else 
     {
         Write-Warning "'$StorageAccountName' storage account not found."
     }
```

You can download detail script from [how to check if a blob exists in Azure Storage using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-check-if-a-blob-145dd882)

Answer (score -1):

You can get a list of all blobs and look for your file.

```
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $config.ImportContainerName -Context $storageContext

ForEach($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $config.LocalImportPath) {
    $blobName = $config.ImportBlobPrefix + "/" + $file.Name
    $blob = $blobs | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $blobName}
    if (-not $file.Length -eq $blob.Length) {
        echo "todo upload" $file.Name
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe for small containers but listing all files isn't scalable at all.

Comment: In that case move the `$blobs` assignment into the loop and add a `-Blob` parameter. But I guess the performance would suffer in most cases.