# Azure CLI not recognizing arguments

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

Trying to run the following command in a Powershell script:

```
    $statblob = az storage blob exists --container-name "dev-tfstate" --name "mh/fw-mh-$varenv-__region__-__suffix__.tfstate" --account-key $blobkey --account-name "fwdevstate767442" --subscription $mgtsub | ConvertFrom-Json
```

And I get the following error:

`ERROR: the following arguments are required: --container-name/-c, --name/-n`

I was getting the same error with the `--account-name` argument until I removed the variable and hard coded the name into the script instead. The values are valid, it just doesn't seem to recognize that the arguments are there?

Edit: I changed the arguments to their aliases of -c and -n, and now I get the error on the account-name argument.

`ERROR: unrecognized arguments: account-name fwdevstate767442`

Comment: probably the issue is the --name, try assigning to a variable and check

Comment: Unfortunately no, that still causes the same error

Comment: try enclosing in '"value"'

Comment: Same result still

Comment: The command runs fine for me. I'm using Azure-CLI v2.17.1 - what Azure CLI version are you working with?

Comment: Looks like I'm running 2.20.0

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your cmdlet. I would suggest you to update your CLI to the most recent version available and then give it a try, sometimes there are some minor flaky issues left out with some specific commands in specific versions.

Comment: I just downgraded the version to 2.17.1, and it's still persisting with the error. Upgraded to the most current version as well 2.22.0, same thing. :/

Comment: Upgrade the CLI version and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a fix. Had to do with variables not being interpreted right for some reason. Setting them as environment variables within the function solved it and the script ran fine afterward.

Comment: Glad that you found the solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

We tried this command without any errors, **the problem might be that you run this Azure CLI command inside your Powershell script.**

There are two solutions:

1. Using Powershell command to check if the blob exists or not.

> [A solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28590164/13586071) is to wrap the call to Get-AzureStorageBlob in a try/catch and catch ResourceNotFoundException to determine that the blob doesn't exist.

2. Change your whole scripts to Azure CLI command.

Comment: I've got same problem in a bash script